# Why this error "CS0165 Use of unassigned local variable" instead of a warning?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-errors

Often I assign null to reference types in the statement that declares the variable. Suppose that I don't.  `Error CS0165    Use of unassigned local variable` can occur at the reference in the Console.WriteLine call. Why is this an error; not a warning?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Person p;
    try
    {
        p = new Person("A");
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    Console.WriteLine(p);
}
```

The error that results...

```
Error   CS0165  Use of unassigned local variable 'p'
```

Aside... assigning null to eliminate the error does not seem to be a "real" solution anyway because there are references such as `p.MyMethod` or `p.MyField` that will give a null reference exception at runtime. How is an error a better design choice than a warning?

Comment: What would the value of `p` be, if an exception is thrown in the `try` block? There is no answer to that, and so it's an error.

Comment: [A "why" question is generally unclear.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/5133585) Please describe what kind of answer you are looking for.

Comment: @Sweeper reference variables are null anyway. It seems a warning would suggest that I make it explicit just as well as an error message.

Comment: "reference variables are null anyway" No they are not. What gave you that idea? Are you suggesting that `Person p;` should implicitly be `Person p = null;`?

Comment: "assigning null to eliminate the error does not seem to be a "real" solution anyway" Who said it is a "real" solution in the first place?

Comment: You would only assign `null` to the variable explicitly and expect it to be a solution if you knew for a fact that a value would always be assigned in between by virtue of the way the application worked. If a `NullReferenceException` could still occur then you haven't actually solved anything. All you've done is assure the compiler that you can be trusted to make it work when you actually can't be.

Comment: The solution here would be to place `Console.WriteLine(p);` inside the try block, after the `p = new  ...`. If the the constructor of `Person` throws an exception, the `WriteLine` won't be executed and instead jump into the catch-block.

Comment: @Sweeper   Check out this link. It says the default of a reference type is null.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values

Comment: @H2ONaCl, yes but local variables are not initialized automatically unlike class fields. A local variable is unassigned until you do it explicitly. A class field would indeed be assigned `null` automatically if you don't initialize it explicitly.

Comment: The *default value* of a type is totally irrelevant to unassigned local variables. While *fields* get initialised to their default values if you don't explicitly initialise them, the same is not true for local variables.

Comment: @Sweeper the refusal to compile (due to classifying something as an error) seems to make the default value of a reference variable irrelevant, as you pointed out.  It seems to me that it didn't have to be that way.  It doesn't bother me hugely that I have to default something that the language explicitly says has a default value, however, it seems strange that it should eliminate an error if my initialization is no different from defaulting.

Comment: Okay, so what exactly is your question? As I said a “why” question is unclear. What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: @Sweeper I read the Lippert discussion about "why" posts. I guess an answer that says "they made it an error because some people ignore warnings" would be the kind of answer I expected.  Or just "your wrong, here's why" is a better answer.

Comment: Types have a default value. E.g. `null` for all reference types, `0`, for `int`, `false` for `bool`, etc. This does not mean that this default value is assigned to variables by default. Class and struct fields are assigned this default value by the constructor. Local variables, i.e., variables declared in methods, are **not** assigned any value by default.

Comment: `The C# compiler doesn't allow the use of uninitialized variables`.  Look at here https://dotnetfiddle.net/Uqbdr8

Comment: @Sweeper FYI Visual Studio, for what it's worth will show you that an uninitialized local variable is null.  `string s; Debug.Assert(false);`  Visual Studio will stop at the assertion and if you hover the cursor over the variable it will be null.

Answer (score 1):

A rule of thumb for warning / error:

- Warining: the code can be compiled and run, but there's a flaw in it which may cause unwanted behaviour
- Error: the code can't be compiled.

Your code can't be compiled (that's why you have error):

```
// Not initialized, p contais trash
Person p;

try
{
    // If constructor throws exception, no assignment will do; 
    // p still will be trash
    p = new Person("A");
}
catch
{
}

// If p is not assigned (due to exception in the constructor);
// p still contains trash.
// This code can't be compiled (printing out trash) - error
Console.WriteLine(p);
```

If you assign `p` to `null` you can turn into Warning:

```
// p is null
Person p = null;

try
{
    // If constructor throws exception, p will be null
    p = new Person("A");
}
catch
{
}

// If p is null (due to exception in the constructor)
// p will be null and we'll have another exception thrown
// That's, probably, not what we're going to have
// So we have warning  
Console.WriteLine(p.ToString());
```

The solution is to operate with `p` within `try`:

```
// Not initialized, p contais trash
Person p;

try
{
    p = new Person("A");

    // p is guaranteed to be created here
    Console.WriteLine(p);
}
catch
{
    // p still contains trash
}
```

Comment: Maybe it can't compile simply because of the design choice that it is an error. If the design choice is that it is a warning, then `p` should have the default value (which might cause unwanted runtime behavior).